# Magento override Mage/Core - check for enabled yes/no, if no default to core

Tags: php, extensions, overrides

We have code where we override Mage_Catalog_Model_Url

```
class SNH_CategoryParentUrl_Catalog_Model_Product_Url extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Url
{
    public function getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath)
    {
```

in the override we check for enabled yes/no

```
$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/seo/category_use_parentcategory',Mage::app()->getStore());

if (null === $configValue || $configValue) {
```

So if it is null (not set) or yes (=default) the code is executed

But what I rather would have is that if the settings is null or enabled - that the whole override is not used but rather the `Mage Core file (for better upgrade protection)`

**Question:** How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
if (null === $configValue || $configValue) {

     return parent::getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath);
}
```

Comment: super! ...........

Comment: ahum. Above the public funtion call? or in the public function call?